# Некорретно обрабатываются регулярные выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения, c++11

Здравствуйте. Есть следующий пример:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main() {

    std::string str("subject, subbase");
    std::regex rx("sub\\w*");
    std::smatch res;

    std::regex_search(str, res, rx);     

    for(auto &i: res) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:
subject

Я ожидал вывод обоих слов из **str**, и [тут](http://regexpal.com) мне подсвечивают как раз оба слова. G++ (GCC) 6.1.1 . Может я не правильно понял принцип работы функции regex_search? Она должна все совпадения внести в res, всё вроде верно.

Comment: короче самому интересно стало, но ответ, ессно гуглится по запросу regex_search multiple results c++, и находится, видимо, здесь http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667295/how-to-match-multiple-results-using-stdregex

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Этот вопрос касается исключительно [tag:c++11]?

Answer (score 5):

Цикл

```cpp
for(auto &i: res)
    std::cout << i << " ";
```

проходит по *захваченным группам* в результате поиска.
Если вашу регулярку записать, например, в таком виде:

```cpp
std::regex rx("(sub)(\\w*)");
```

то будут захвачены следующие группы:

> subject sub ject

Чтобы сматчить все слова, соответствующие вашей регулярке, можно использовать код:

```cpp
while (std::regex_search (str, res, rx)) {
    std::cout << res[0] << " ";
    str = res.suffix();
}
```

Пример использования `regex_search` можно посмотреть, например, [здесь](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_search/).